# Minimum number of iterations required to introduce all n people to all $n$ in groups of size s?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

I'm not sure if this is a well researched problem, I'm trying to think of a solution, it does not seem very obvious.

For eg: If $n = 6$ and $s = 3$, we can introduce everyone in $4$ iterations

```
1) A B C | D E F
2) A E F | D B C
3) A D E | F B C
4) A D F | E B C
```

I don't want to figure out a scheme of grouping manually for $n = 12$ and $s = 3$, please point me to relevant discussion or literature, if someone identifies what problem it is.

Comment: Just to check my understanding of what you're saying... so there are $\left(n\atop s\right)=n!/s!(n-s)!$ possible groups of size $s$ in all, right? And we're always choosing an $s$ such that $n=ks$ is an integer multiple $k$ of $s$? Then, for a solution, you could always program it... generate all $\left(n\atop s\right)$ groups, check which subsets introduce everybody to each other, and select the smallest such subset(s) (plural in case there are ties). Studying the numerical results might suggest a closed-form solution.

Comment: As far as I understand, there will be 12 C 3 = 220 groups, and there are 2 ^ 220 subsets of those groups, it is not trivial to go through all of them. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, I certainly missed something. Hadn't focused on your $12c3$, and had therefore missed the $2^{220}$. But you might try programming the general $(n,s)$ case, and then running it for smaller/tractable numbers, and then seeing if you can recognize what closed-form function $N_{min}(n,s)$ fits all the computed results, which would then presumably extrapolate to $(12,3)$. In fact, by examining the subsets comprising those $N_{min}$'s, you might even see how to explicitly construct them for the general case. Granted, odds are small that you'll discover all this numerically, but you could try.

Comment: To add a little pessimistic note, for s = 3 such decomposition of clique into $\frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{6}$ triangles is known as Steiner triples and is already very nontrivial.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $n$ vertices (the number of people).

You defined an operation, that takes $2s$ vertices, and connects them by edges (disregarding the current edges between them) to construct the graph $K_{s,s}$ (Complete bipartite graph).

You asked whats the minimal number of rounds required to construct the graph $K_n$.
Since $\vert E \vert = {n \choose 2}$, and you add at most $s^2$ edges each time, a lower bound on the number of rounds you must perform is ceil of $\frac{{n \choose 2}}{s^2}$

It wasn't clear to me if you are looking for an number or an algorithm to find a solution, so here is an algorithm:

I'm not sure if a greedy algorithm will obtain the optimal result, but it will obtain $O(ln(s))$ approximation. (multiplicative factor)

Great question!